# how to align all text on left side and image on right size

Tags: html, css

How to apply css and html to design a template like below which text on left side and picture image on right side (small portion)?

i tried with `table` method with two columns two rows but it looks, the wording cannot display at once have to seperate in different rows.

Comment: no code no help possible, just guess ... typical float example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `float` can help you.

```css
div {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
img{
width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.visiontravel.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sailing-ship-300x300.jpg"><br>CSS is fun!
</div>

<p>
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>

<p>
In the paragraph above, the div element is 120 pixels wide and it contains the image.
The div element will float to the right. Margins are added to the div to push the text away from the div.
Borders and padding are added to the div to frame in the picture and the caption.
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @mmativ, sweet, this is what im looking for. Thank so much.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a table. Use a , put all the text and image in the parent  then in the image style specify float property to right.

That's is id/class img{float:right;}